# "Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: node.js, typescript, swagger, query-string

I am using node + typescript and integrated swagger for API Calls. I have a following request in swagger

> http://localhost:3033/employees/search/?username=test

*Here I want to find the records having username = test.*

So I parse the query string using URL module, like below and I am getting the username in my console.

```
var params = URL.parse(req.url, true).query;
console.log(params); //gives me [Object: null prototype] { username: 'test' } in my console
```

But whenever I try to assign params.username to a constant like below

```
const username:string =params.username;
```

It gives me the following error

> Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
>     Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

My full code is as below

```
import * as URL from 'url';

public getUserByName = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
var params = URL.parse(req.url, true).query;
const username:string =params.username;

try {
  const findOneUserData: Employee = await this.userService.findUserByName(username);
  res.status(200).json({ data: findOneUserData, message: 'findOne' });
} catch (error) {
  next(error);
}
```

}

Comment: What library do you use for `URL.parse`?

Comment: url package : I've included import * as URL from 'url'; at top of my controller

Comment: Hmm, I can't find for sure what that library is. There seems to be one called "querystring" and a different one called "url". Perhaps the latter uses the former? Not sure, but I did find [this type definition for `ParsedUrlQuery`](https://github.com/jeffreywescott/DefinitelyTyped/blob/59e1039b5696ab9be1a4fd1e068b126587eb7d9f/types/node/index.d.ts#L1095), so it doesn't seem to be a string - it's either an array or an object with string keys and values. At least according to this type definition. If you get "test" in the console, I'd assume it's actually `["test"]` - an array

Comment: Can you create a minimum working example using [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/)?

Comment: Can you check `console.log(params)` again? It should print an object containing `username` property (just tested that)

Comment: @ford04 : i got this.. [Object: null prototype] { username: 'test' }

Comment: @ford04 : Okay I got the mistake I made there. I updated my question, now I got another error

Comment: Have a look at the type declaration @VLAZ already posted above. You probably want to do some narrowing before, e.g. `Array.isArray(params.username)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay ,so I got the mistake that I made. The first one was what @ford04 has mentioned in the comment. I was directly assigning Object to the string. I changed it in my question. The second was converted the parsed query-string to string by `toString()` function.

```
public getUserByName = async(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  var params = URL.parse(req.url, true).query;
  console.log(params.username);
  const username: string = params.username.toString(); //this is the key

  try {
    const findOneUserData: Employee = await this.userService.findUserByName(username);
    res.status(200).json({
      data: findOneUserData,
      message: 'findOne'
    });
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The problem in your code is, that params.username can be either a `string` or a `string[]`.

The following scenario returns a simple string

```
const {query} = url.parse('example.com?test=1', true);
// query.test === '1'
```

while the example below returns an array because the same query-parameter key is used twice

```
const {query} = url.parse('example.com?test=1&test=2', true);
//query.test === ['1', '2']
```

So you could handle the array case explicitly e.g.

```
const username = Array.isArray(params.username) ? params.username[0] : params.username
```

Comment: That's what I'm doing too. It just feels wrong, though: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71273690/470749

Answer (score 2):

You can tell the compiler to cast the param as a string with

```
const username = params.username as string
```

Comment: I upvoted this but then read "[This] would cause a runtime error if the query param is an array. When casting you're simply making TypeScript happy, not preventing the error from happening." https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273690/how-to-use-query-params-in-next-js?noredirect=1#comment125994147_71273690