# nextjs API with typescript, restricting NextApiRequest query param to just string type

Tags: typescript, next.js

In this endpoint handler, is there a way to restrict `req.query` in NextJS `NextApiRequest` to just `string` types rather than `string | string[]`. For example, `someQueryParam` here is of `string | string[]` type but I want to use it as just `string` type

```
export default async function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Response>
) {

   const { someQueryParam } = req.query;
   
   // pass in someQueryParam as a string into a function call
   const result = functionCall(someQueryParam)
}
```

typescript error when passing someQueryParam into a function that only accepts `string` type for the argument:

```
Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

For reference, here is the definition of `NextApiRequest` in the Nextjs library

[image: nextjs NextApiRequest]

also open to any suggestions to somehow use `someQueryParam` as `string` type rather than `string | string[]` type within the handler before passing it into function

Comment: Does this answer your question: ["Type 'string | string\[\]' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110364/type-string-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)? You'll want to narrow the `someQueryParam` value down to a string.

Comment: This is how I'm handling it (although it's not perfect): https://stackoverflow.com/q/71273690/470749

Comment: req.query as unknown as MyType

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The underlining issue is that the web address protocol allows assigning of multiple query names with the same name. These then get passed as a `string[]` instead of a single string.

E.g, `?value=one&value=two`. Therefore it should be up to the app to decide which value to accept if it's only going to make use of one string.

`const value = Array.isArray(params.value) ? params.value[0] : params.value`