# Passing NextJs req.query parameter to Prisma where structure

Tags: javascript, next.js, query-string, prisma

I am learning NextJS and I am trying to send a request to the API with a parameter and this parameter is passed to Prisma to query the database.

I have created a file in `/api/posts/[slug].ts` and I am sending a request as `/api/posts/this-is-my-slug`.

I then do the following to extract the slug parameter from the URL using the below:

```
const { slug } = req.query;
```

I am then trying to pass slug to the where in the prisma query as below:

```
const article = await prismaClient.posts.findFirst({
    where: {
        slug: slug
    }
})
```

But I am getting the following error

> TS2322: Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string |
> StringFilter'.   Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string |
> StringFilter'.

Below is my prisma schema model for the posts table

```
model posts {
    id          Int         @id @default(autoincrement())
    createdAt   DateTime    @default(now())
    title       String      @db.VarChar(255)
    content     String      @db.MediumText
    slug        String      @db.VarChar(255)
    published   Boolean     @default(false)
    author      users       @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [userId])
    authorId    Int
}
```

I don't get what the error is, if I hardcode the slug string no errors in the IDE are shown, but using the variable from the req.query isn't happy for some reason.

Comment: Check one of these out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72287641/941770 https://stackoverflow.com/a/63884522/941770 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71273690/how-to-use-query-params-in-next-js

Comment: I have done the as string or .toString in those examples, but why would I need to. Prisma is generating the types so what's making it think that I have a single post record, the slug could be either `String` or `String[]`. Doesn't seem correct that I have to cast it to force it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`context.query` (or `req.query`) actually represents the query string (and also includes dynamic route parameters), that's why it types everything as `string | string[]`, because query allows multiple entries with the same name.

If you were using `getServerSideProps` you could use `context.params.slug`, you would need to correctly type the function of course, something along this lines:

```
type Params = { slug: string };

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<Props, Params> = () => {/* ... */}
```

But for a Next.js API route it's not possible, so you have to use `query` and cast `string | string[]` to an array and then grab first element, for example.

And as for Prisma, it actually expects just one string, not an array, unless you use other operators, for example you could use `in` to find between multiple slugs:

```
    prisma.posts.findFirst({
      where: {
        slug: {
          // Now you need to pass an array here, not a string
          in: ['abc', 'fgh']
        }
      }
    })
```

[More info about filters and operators](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/prisma-client-reference#filter-conditions-and-operators)

Comment: Although this will make TypeScript happy, I would highly recommend narrowing down the query string value to a `string` instead. Overriding the query params type can lead to a false safety because it can still be of type `string[]` (that's why it's typed that way), e.g. `/api/post?slug=first-value&slug=second-value`.

Comment: @juliomalves but I think he does not use query at all, it's just a dynamic route param? If it was a query then sure, you should handle both `string` and `string[]`.

Comment: Second generic for `GetServerSideProps` is for `params` property only, you cannot override `GetServerSidePropsContext.query`, it always equals to `ParsedUrlQuery` (basically `Record<string, string | string []>)

Comment: I believe OP is using an API route, not `getServerSideProps`. Hence why they're using `const { slug } = req.query;`. And just because OP isn't using multiple `slug` values, it doesn't mean someone else couldn't.

Comment: Oh, I see, I missed that part the he is using api route, he can't access `params` there. Well yes, as I said, for query it's possible to have multiple values with same name in this case, but for params it's not possible, that's why you can specify a generic for it in  `GetServerSideProps`, so the answer still stands