# NextJS: NextApiRequest not working well with query

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
export default function handler(
  req: NextApiRequest,
  res: NextApiResponse<Data>
) {

  const searchTerm: string = req.query.searchTerm
  ......
```

Typescript error:
`Type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'. Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.`

How to make NextApiRequest play nice with Typescript when using query?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Type 'string | string\[\]' is not assignable to type 'string'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60110364/type-string-string-is-not-assignable-to-type-string)

Comment: This is how I'm handling it (although it's not perfect): https://stackoverflow.com/q/71273690/470749